# Unable to initialise embedded struct

Tags: go

I have the following structs declared in packageA

```
type FlagSkel struct {
    Name    string
    Short   string
    HelpMsg string
}

type FlagString struct {
    Value        string
    DefaultValue string
}

type CompositeFlagString struct {
    FlagSkel
    FlagString
}
```

In another package, I am trying to initialise (outside any function) a `var` of the later type as follows:

```
var Name = packageA.CompositeFlagString{
    FlagSkel: {
        Name:    "name",
        Short:   "",
        HelpMsg: "Something here",
    },
    FlagString: {
        DefaultValue: "",
    },
}
```

However vscode compiler shows me the attached error

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the type for the struct literals:

```
packageA.CompositeFlagString{
    FlagSkel: packageA.FlagSkel{
        Name:    "name",
        Short:   "",
        HelpMsg: "Something here",
    },
    FlagString: packageA.FlagString{
        DefaultValue: "",
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to set the type of your inner structs you want to create.
your variable initialisation should be:

```
var Name = packageA.CompositeFlagString{
    FlagSkel: packageA.FlagSkel {
        Name:    "name",
        Short:   "",
        HelpMsg: "Something here",
    },
    FlagString: packageA.FlagString {
        DefaultValue: "",
    },
}
```

If you change this, it should work.

Comment: You are right, I didn't know this syntax. I corrected my post.